# Nest Js, how to correctly set _id property in your schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I know it seems quite basic, but I can't seem to find the correct way of setting up the _id field in the Nest.js mongoose schema.
I've attached an image, and was just wondering what the best way to set this property? I get the following error

> 'SchemaType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace
> here.ts(2702)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to define `_id` as a prop because it already exists in the `Document` class. Queries performed against your `MusicSupervisorModel` will return an object of `MusicSupervisorDocument`. In case you want to add a field of `ObjectId` type to your schema you have to do it as follows to preserve casting to `ObjectId`:

```js
import { Document, SchemaTypes, Types } from 'mongoose';

...

@Prop({ type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId })
yourField: Types.ObjectId
```

Comment: and what do u set a parameter type when u want to receive the model instance and then access the _id on that instance...

If I will just type a param as the model class _id is not defined on the schema and typescript has the problem with that:


for example:
User Model:
`@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop()
  name?: string;

}`
Some Service:
`async someActoin(user: User) {
    // ERROR: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(2339)
    console.log(user._id)
  }`

Answer (score 1):

When defining your Mongoose schema in NestJS you really don't have to specify the _id field and all will be fine.

If you want to explicitly define it you have to use following:

```
...

 _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId

...
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party and I'm not strictly answering the question, but this might still be helpful for some. This is in response the Tornike Menabde's comment.

You can use the `HydratedDocument` type from the mongoose package to access the properties, that are being added automatically by mongoose or mongo, i.e. `_id`.

```js
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema()
export class User {
  // no _id required here
}
```

The type UserDocument looks like this: `type UserDocument = Document<unknown, {}, User> & User & { _id: Types.ObjectId; }`, so it already includes the '_id' property.